# Python regex and using s/ in pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex pattern that when I use in vim works great:

```
s/\.[A-Za-z0-9_]*\(IPROC\|IFIX\|IPTAT\)[A-Za-z_]*\([0-9][0-9]*\)[^0-9]*.*([A-Za-z0-9_]*\(IPROC\|IFIX\|IPTAT\)[A-Za-z_]*\([0-9][0-9]*\)[^0-9]*.*)/\3_\4
```

I am searching for things like `.jalsdkjflkajsdf_lajsdlfIFIX_100(IFIX_asdf_200)`

It will return: `IFIX_200` (the last part). I can also set it to return buffers 1 and 2 so I can get `IFIX_100` (the first part).

How can I use this reg expression in python to return what is expected. I've tried each of the re.findall and re.search, and no luck.

```
patternI1 = 's/\.[A-Za-z0-9_]*\(IPROC|IFIX|IPTAT\)[A-Za-z_]*\([0-9][0-9]*\)[^0-9]*.*([A-Za-z0-9_]*\(IPROC|IFIX|IPTAT\)[A-Za-z_]*\([0-9][0-9]*\)[^0-9]*.*)/\3_\4'
with open(filename) as input_file:
  for num, line in enumerate(input_file, 1):
    if re.search(patternI1, line):
      x = re.findall(patternI1, line)
    print x
```

Comment: when you have backslashes inside a regex . prepend "r" to the quotes .

r'something\('

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave of the `s/ ... /3_4`; that's Vim search-and-replace syntax. Vim also uses metacharacters differently, do *not* escape the `(..)` parenthesis of a group, but *do* escape literal `()` parenthesis.

`\w` is a nice shortcut for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, and `\d` will do for `[0-9]`, `\D` for `[^0-9]`, using `\d+` where `\d\d*` was used:

```
patternI1 = r'\.\w*(IPROC|IFIX|IPTAT)\w*?(\d+)\D*.*\(\w*(IPROC|IFIX|IPTAT)\w*?(\d+)\D*.*\)'
```

I've adjusted the greedyness of the `\w*` pattern before the digits groups to prevent these from swallowing too many digits too. Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> sample = '.jalsdkjflkajsdf_lajsdlfIFIX_100(IFIX_asdf_200)'
>>> patternI1 = r'\.\w*(IPROC|IFIX|IPTAT)\w*?(\d\d*)\D*.*\(\w*(IPROC|IFIX|IPTAT)\w*?(\d\d*)\D*.*\)'
>>> re.search(patternI1, sample).groups()
('IFIX', '100', 'IFIX', '200')
```

Comment: As an FYI to the OP, Python uses's Perl's regular expression syntax, whereas Vim use's UNIX regular expression syntax.  This is why one cannot directly use Vim regex in Python or vice versa.

Comment: What would happen if I had two instances of my example in the same line? Would it return all 8 expressions?

Comment: @user2658799: It'd return just the first 4; you'd have to make all `*` quantifiers non-greedy (add a `?` to them if not yet there), then use `re.findall()` instead of `re.search()` to return a list of tuples; each entry in that list is then a tuple of 4 values.

Comment: @user2658799: so `patternI1 = r'\.\w*?(IPROC|IFIX|IPTAT)\w*?(\d\d*)\D*?.*?\(\w*?(IPROC|IFIX|IPTAT)\w*?(\d\d*)\D*?.*?\)'`, then `re.findall(patternI1, inputstring)`.